# Is there a way to disable all scrolling online? (for desktop)

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, applications, web-browser, macos

I am looking for a solution primarily for macbook and desktop use and in a web browser - possibly an extension or plug in.

I have an inner ear condition and scrolling makes me dizzy.

It is a long shot but is there anything at all I can do to not have to look at the scrolling page? Is there any browser extension or similar that would revert the scrolling experience back to a page by page view? Or any other way you can think of which would allow me to do page-by-page scrolling?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. I've put a hold on this since there's no clear Apple Product you wish to learn about scrolling. It could be the watch or something else. Just have a look at the help links and then make an edit so that it's clear which Apple product or verision you're looking to understand scroll options and the hold will be reviewed by the community of reviewers we have around the globe.

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly then it **sounds like** you may be asking for the functionality built into most keyboards, but not the small Apple keyboards. That is the "page up" and "Page Down" keys. If you have a Macbook FN + Up/Down arrow keys do the same thing as Page Up/Down. Does that do it or did I misunderstand?

Comment: Hi Steve thanks for your thought on this one.. The problem with the arrow /up down keys is that there is still movement of the page on display - It still scrolls. I wonder if their is an extension for any browser that reverts the scrolling operation back to a page by page view? Similar to the early days of the internet when content was loaded page by page. I would like to just see static pages of content and to have two keys or a browser tab that provides this function moves the web page up or down, without the scroll and relative to my browser window size.

Comment: I've edited your question to focus on feasible/practical solutions. If you are looking for ways to develop something like this yourself there are better sites to ask than AD (as most coding questions are off-topic here).

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're most likely interested in is disabling a certain animation. 
I'm on Mojave, but the following command supposedly works since Mountain Lion (I tested it with Numbers and Safari):

```
defaults write -g NSScrollAnimationEnabled -bool NO
```

In case you don't know how to enter this: Open the `Terminal` application (it's in Applications - Utilities, or you just open it using Spotlight) and enter the command there. You will need to restart an application for it to have an effect (e.g. Safari won't only change behavior after you do that).

This should affect all applications unless the developers did some weird custom stuff to move around a scroll view.

What it does is, I think, exactly what you want: It disables the scrolling animation when you press the "PageUp" and "PageDown" buttons.

Actually I guess it disables animations during scrolling in general, but when using the scroll wheel or the regular arrow keys the jumped distance is so small that subsequent jumps result in a "manual animation" anyways (animations are after all just a row of still images with small differences shown quickly one after another).

Comment: Thanks Gero! I will certainly give this a try.. I am comfortable with basic use in Terminal so no problem there. Am I right in thinking if I want to return to the normal state I can type into Terminal the same text but with the change at the end - 'defaults write -g NSScrollAnimationEnabled -bool YES'

Comment: exactly. that's how I returned to my normal settings as well. :)